# Adjusting UIImageView in UIScrollView of custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using custom UICollectionViewCell, the cell contains one UIImageView of size (320,145), but I need to display image of 400 x 400 into that, so I am trying to use UIScrollView to display whole image without cropping it, i.e. user can scroll to see whole image in parts.

I added my imageView in scrollView with giving proper frame size and content size to scrollView as given in following code. But still image is not looking properly, I can see the image is becomes small to fit the screen, I can see the whole image and scroll also, but I want to see full image i.e. 400 x 400.

```
UIScrollView * imgScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 145)];
[imgScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[imgScrollView setClipsToBounds:YES];
[imgScrollView addSubview:_albumImageView];
[imgScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

[imgScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400, 400)];  /// my _albumImageView is of 400 x 400 

_albumImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
_albumImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

[self.contentView addSubview:imgScrollView];
```

The output of above code is looking as below Screenshot
[image]

but I want it as below screenshot with scroll enable.(the image may be different with same size)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you've set the contentMode property to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`

```
_albumImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

which will cause the image to resize to fill the frame (320x145).

**EDIT:**

Also, is the image in your _albumImageView a *resizable* UIImage?  If not, make it resizable with

```
UIImage *img = [albumImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

before adding it to your `_albumImageView`

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but image is still not looking scaled, it aligned to centre of scrollView but not does not have size as 400 x 400.

Comment: and I want to fit it in 400 x 400 as its original image size, and need to display that with scroll in 320 x 145 cell.

Comment: Edited answer to add something else to try - make sure your image is resizable

Answer (score 0):

Try this

_albumImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;